# PHP security, only allow $_REQUEST from specific URL

Tags: php

I have a simple PHP script which accepts a `$_REQUEST` from a javascript Ajax call and adds a post to the DB

But I need to ensure that only javascript requests from my domain is allowed, to prevent someone from submitting thousands of junk posts to my DB.

My question is, how do I ensure that my script only accepts `$_REQUEST` from my domain?

Thanks

Comment: This question does not show any research effort at all

Comment: Maybe if you can tell me which sort of terms I should search then it would be helpful, I have tried researching but my terms come up with zero relevancy

Comment: How about "PHP, secure post user validation"?
http://blackbe.lt/php-secure-sessions/

Or http://serverfault.com/questions/583884/apache-listen-only-on-specific-domain-not-ip

This one would require you to adapt it for your needs, but doable.

And also:
http://bobby-tables.com/php.html

might be of use

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: You can't.

It *sounds* like you need to introduce the usual defences against CSRF (i.e. to generate a random security token and store it in a cookie (or session) as well as in your HTML document. You then submit the token as part of your request and compare it to the one in the cookie. If they match, then it is an intentional post from the user and not their browser being tricked into making the request by another site).

This won't stop people submitting "thousands of junk posts" though. You also need to authenticate users and check they are authorised to make a submission before allowing it to go through.

You can consider also including rate limiting checks and spam filtering.

Comment: Okay, how about another way. Since my PHP script is normally only called via an Ajax request from my site, can I detect the incoming Ajax call's URL and if it doesn't match my domain, don't perform anything

Comment: No, you cannot. (At least not reliably enough to be worth using).

Comment: Why is it not reliable enough? Any information is really really helpful for me

Comment: I suppose you can check $_SERVER parameters (HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR, HTTP_CLIENT_IP and REMOTE_ADDR)... but would not recommend using this. Not reliable and highly variable depending on your server configuration.

Comment: Also, what do you mean AJAX request from your site? Are you sending a CURL request?

Comment: @Takuya — The question is a bit fuzzily worded, but I'm pretty sure it is asking to check where the HTML document from which the Ajax request is triggered is hosted and not if the browser is running on the same computer as the server.

Comment: @Takuya — If you want to ask for clarification of the question, please comment on the question and not on an answer to it.

Comment: I'm just submitting a simple $_POST ajax call to my php file

Comment: @Takuya can you please elaborate a little bit on why is it not recommended? Thank You

Comment: @Quentin I'm asking for clarification in regards to his comment that is in response to your answer, which is why I'm asked for clarification here.

  --EDIT: $_SERVER holds information about the environment the script was executed in including, as indicated, the "known" IP address where the request came from. The indicated array parameters are not related to the server itself.

Comment: The $_SERVER parameters may not contain the client IP address. It can be the proxy server in use for example. I have no idea what happens if your server using something like nginx.

Comment: The referer header, which is what matters here, is optional, often omitted, and easily forged.

Comment: Can't I use $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] which returns the name of my host server?

Comment: Yes, but as @Quentin and I allude to, it is not reliable and no one should use it in a production environment

Comment: @Takuya — As I powered out earlier, the IP the request came from (i.e. the IP of the browser) isn't relevant to the problem.

Comment: @Quentin perhaps we have different understandings of the process involved. Please correct me if I am mistaken. I was envisioning: BROWSER -> SERVER -> SERVER ($_POST API). But what it seems is happening from the description is BROWSER -> SERVER. Am I mistaken?

Comment: To me it sounds like: Browser gets HTML from server. HTML includes JS. JS instructs browser to make another request to the server. The goal is to ensure that the second request is triggered only by the JS in the HTML from the server.

Comment: Sorry for all of the confusion, it would be BROWSER -> SERVER in my case. A simple js ajax call from an HTML file to a simple PHP file. That PHP file would perform the functions to create posts in my DB

Comment: Why limit it to domain only then? For example: User (request not from "example.com") -> REQUEST TO example.com -> REJECTED. Seems to me what your after is user authentication?

Comment: @Takuya — So … what I said in this answer then?

Comment: @Quentin yes exactly, except you didn't say "user authentication", which is a key search term that might help the OP. Sorry if this comes across as aggressive, I'm not trying to be, just trying to be helpful. I am just slightly confused over the intended use case (as in, if there is a legitimate reason for structuring it this way. Maybe a site with no registered users?). I've +1'd your answer btw.

Comment: I suppose if no user registration, you could use a dynamically generated unique ID (UID) with a very short expiry?
SERVER sends document with UID -> CLIENT/BROWSER sends Ajax with UID -> SERVER checks that UID is valid. Problem with this is the time taken for document to be sent and retrieved is variable, so the UID may be invalid by the time the CLIENT sends it

Comment: No. If you generate a UID on demand, then an attacker trying to flood the system with junk messages can acquire new UIDs freely.

Comment: @Quentin quite right. Unless the ajax post is sent after some form of validation happens (i.e. some form of captcha, but this only filters out some bots). But yes, my suggestion was stupid. It's quite late here, need to go to bed soon.

Answer (score 0):

You use a 'secret' key, a response and a remote IP to validate.

Google has provided this for you

- https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify
- https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display
- https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible#auto_render

works like a charm.
Once you implement you get an **ADMIN panel** here:

- https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin

At which time you set the **Domains to be ONLY your URL's**.

Which will do what you want and make sure the form validates from your domain using both keys from server side and client side integration. If someone try's to generate the "key" using their domain recaptcha will detect it as spam. 
(see the verify link above)

[image]